@Autowired is existing, but @Bean required says
There is some error which says bean required for this declaration and is not allowing server to start. When I define a bean says bean not allowed for this location. And throws an error. What should I do now???
i expect server to start, but this not allowing.

Start by pasting exact and correctly formatted error message into the question

where are you using the @Bean? You must use it on a method in a class annotated with @Configuration. Other ways to create a bean include using the stereotype annotations. But to conclude what's wrong, you would have to share the error message and the minimal viable code.
